# Error While Picking Image - Expo and react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using the expo image picker library to upload a image. However when i run it in the simulator and choose an image i get this error: `Error while picking image: [Error: Failed to write data to a file → Caused by: The folder “566A6DD9-7A12-4281-8473-17A1A4A5BAD0.jpg” doesn’t exist.]`

How do i fix this error? If i am not using the simulator on my laptop and use the expo app on my iphone i get this error: `Error while picking image: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.assets[0]')]`
here is the link i am following: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/
Heres is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";

import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default function OnboardAddImages({ navigation }) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const pickImage = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      });
      console.log(result);

      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result.uri);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        setImage(null);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }, 2000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while picking image:", error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={["#A1DDFF", "#FFE3B9", "#FECBFF"]}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/BackArrow.png")}
            style={styles.backarrow}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.content}>
      
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
        >
          {!image ? (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={pickImage}
                style={{
                  borderStyle: "dashed",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: "#000000",
                  padding: 10,
                }}
              >
                {isLoading ? (
                  <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                      color={"#ff0000"}
                      animating
                      size={"large"}
                    />
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <Text>Pick a image</Text>
                )}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
            // display a image

              {image && (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                <Image source={{uri:image}} />

                </View>
              )}
              </>
          )}


        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NextPage")}
        >
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/frontarrow.png")}
            style={styles.frontarrow}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </LinearGradient>
  );
}

});
```